# Modal View in Swift

Tags: swift, modal-dialog

I have spent more than couple hours but still cant get the modal view working. I am following this youtube video - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k-GvIqh5Xcs

Segue settings - 
Kind: Present Modally
Presentation: Default
Transition: Default

Destination view controller
Transition Style: Cross Dissolve
Presentation: Over current context

View settings
Background: White
Opacity: 50%

Drawing: 
Check - Opaque, Clears Graphics context, Auto resize subviews.

Dont know what should be Tint?

I get Grey background and cant see the previous view in background. Help Please.

Comment: Off the top of my head, `Presentation` should be `Over Current Context`

Comment: without your code (and maybe screenshots) nobody can help :(

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out... 
I had this in presenting view 
func adaptivePresentationStyleForPresentationController(controller: UIPresentationController) -> UIModalPresentationStyle {
        return UIModalPresentationStyle.none
    }

removing it works.